# Rails gem Dragonfly default storage path changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, local-storage, dragonfly-gem

Dragonfly saves files under the (**environment**) directory, like:

```
public/system/dragonfly/development/
```

or

```
public/system/dragonfly/production/
```

is it possible to make the common directory and save all under (**dragonfly**) for production and development both?

```
public/system/dragonfly/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help those who has such question:

You should correct the line with root_path in the initializer file config/intializers/dragonfly.rb

```
root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env)
```

and remove Rails.env for the path had no veriables.

```
#config/intializers/dragonfly.rb

require 'dragonfly'

# Configure
Dragonfly.app.configure do
  plugin :imagemagick

  secret "e83b8affbf1c807c7788c07d27e70e79fb0459f8e2c4375b59e60a3da11631e5"

  url_format "/media/:job/:name"

  datastore :file,
    root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
    server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
end

# Logger
Dragonfly.logger = Rails.logger

# Mount as middleware
Rails.application.middleware.use Dragonfly::Middleware

# Add model functionality
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  ActiveRecord::Base.extend Dragonfly::Model
  ActiveRecord::Base.extend Dragonfly::Model::Validations
end
```